# Laravel : How to calculate total marks in Model and return the result as a JSON using The with function

Tags: angularjs, json, laravel

i Have table named Exam

```
  Schema::create('exams', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer ('theory_score');
        $table->integer ('theory_coefficient');
        $table->integer ('practical_score');
        $table->integer ('practical_coefficient');
        $table->date('exam_date');
```

I want in my Model Exam To create a function totalMarks() in order to calculate the total marks of the Exam 
somthings like this

```
class Exam extends Model
    {
     protected $guarded = [];
   public function student() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Student', 'student_id', 'id');
   }
   public function totalMarks(){
     return (($this->theory_score*$this->theory_coefficient)+($this->practical_score*$this->practical_coefficient))/100;
   }
```

and i want to have  query like this using the function with

```
 public function getExam($studentId)
   {
     $exam = Exam::where('student_id','=',$studentId)
     ->with('student','totalMarks')->get()->toJson();
   return $exam; 
   }
```

i Have This error

> "message": "Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on integer",
>       "exception": "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError",

Comment: You can only eager load (using `with`) a relation. `totalMarks` in this case is just a normal method, which is why you're seeing that error. Remove `totalMarks` from `with` and call that method when and where you need it. Would I be correct in thinking you want each student's total marks to appear in the resulting JSON?

Comment: You can use accessor for this job.

Comment: @Jonathon i want to have as a result list of student exam's with total Mark then after that average of each student

Comment: @Kyslik the proble i want a result ready as Json

Comment: @Hbar01 do not, model is responsible talking with data source (database in this case), and controller does the JSON converting - creating a response.

Comment: I think you have flaw in your design, you are computing total marks for "who" / "what entity"? For exam? For student?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) for this job:

```
class Exam extends Model
{

    public function student() {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Student::class, 'student_id', 'id');
    }

    public function getTotalMarksAttribute() {
        return (($this->theory_score*$this->theory_coefficient)+($this->practical_score*$this->practical_coefficient))/100;
    }
...
```

If you want to have this computed when you are getting the model out of the database you use `retrieved` event (the following code belongs to model itself):

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::retrieved(function($exam) {
        $exam->attributes['total_marks'] = $exam->total_marks;
    });
}
```

---

In order to retrieve the computed attribute you use

1. `Exam::where(..)->first()->total_marks // single exam`
2. `Exam::where(..)->get()->pluck('total_marks') // collection of exams`

Comment: @Hbar01 You just call `Exam::where('student_id', $studentId)->first()->total_marks` you will have the computed attribute. I edited the post so you have the computed attribute always ready (using the retrieved event).

Comment: @Hbar01, I accidentally deleted the comment above yours... Will add it to the answer itself. No problem. Good luck!

Comment: i have one additional problem now when i update the exam table i get new error `"Column not found: 1054 Unknown column total_marks"  "in 'field list' (SQL: update....`